# Remove-ADComputer with -Credential param not working

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I was hoping maybe someone could help me out. I'm running a simple command that will remove an AD computer object using the `ActiveDirectory` Module. I'm passing a credential but I keep getting `Access Denied`. I checked the account and it has rights to delete.

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\Logs\DeleteComObj.txt"
$username = 'MyDomain\ServiceAccount'
$password = ConvertFrom-Base64 -Value 'TgBpAGMAZQBUAHIAeQAhAA=='
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username,$securePassword
Remove-ADComputer -Identity "TestComObj" -Confirm:$false -Credential $credential
Stop-Transcript
```

The error says the following:

```
TerminatingError(Remove-ADComputer): "Access is denied"
Remove-ADComputer : Access is denied
At C:\Posh\RemoveADObj.ps1:6 char:1
+ Remove-ADComputer -Credential $credential -Identity "TestComObj" -C ...
```

Would there be any other reason why passing creds with `Remove-ADComputer` would not be working?

Comment: Is the user an administrator ? Are the credentials correct ?

Comment: Is the AD object protected? If so, it would need the deletion protection disabled and then the command run against it.

Comment: Yes, the user is an administrator and the serviceaccout has rights to delete objects from the OU.  

The "Protect object from accidental deletion" is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the cmdlet works, the problem was the servicingaccount. I had my IDM team create a new service account.  The servicingaccount I was trying to use was not setup properly.

Apologies everyone.